# Correct AST for Parsing Algebra

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, algebra

What is the correct [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) for representing algebra? I have tried way too many setups, and constantly been rewriting the syntax tree, and all of my configurations end up forgetting something important (e.g. fractions not being supported). Currently my configurations for equations and expressions seem to be fine. Expressions simply consist of an array of terms, each with a positive/negative sign, and a coefficient. That's where the trouble comes in. What *exactly* is a term? Wikipedia helps some, and even has an [example AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_(mathematics)#Formal_definition) for a couple of terms. However, for practical purposes I'm trying to keep everything closer to the concepts we use when we learn algebra, rather than breaking it down into nothing but variables and operators. It appears that just about anything can be contained in a term: terms can contain fractions (which contain expressions), sub-terms, sub-expressions, and regular variables, each of them having their own exponents.
Currently my configuration is something like this:

```
                                      Term
                                        |
         -----------------------------------------------------------------
         |                |             |                 |              |     
     Coefficient   ArrayList of     ArrayList of      ArrayList of   ArrayList of
         |         sub-expressions  powers of         fractions      powers of  
         |                          sub-expressions*  (may contain   fractions*
     ---------------                                  variables)
     |             |
integer/decimal  fraction
                 (no variables)
```

*Expressions/fractions don't have exponents on their own, but may have one outside sometimes (e.g. `2(x+3)^3`).

NOTE: For the sake of simplicity the diagram leaves out an ArrayList of variables (and one for roots), an an ArrayList of their respective exponents, all contained by the term.

NOTE 2: In case it's not clear, the diagram doesn't show inheritance. It's showing members of the Term class.

This seems rather sloppy to me, and might not scale well with the project when things get more complex. *Is a term really supposed to be this kind of soup?* I have a feeling yet another thing should be included in term, but I can't think of what it would be. Although I've been strugling with this for some months, I haven't taken the discipline to just stop and *really* work it out, which I should have done before starting.

Am I making a mistake in making nearly everything fit in a term? If so, what should I be doing instead? If not, is it really supposed to be this... ugly/non-intuitive? Part of my feeling that this must be wrong is due to the fact that that almost no one thinks of an algebraic term this way.

Example term: `2.3x(2/3)^4(√23)((x+6)/(x-6))` (overly complex, I know, but it contains everything mentioned above).

My real question: What is the correct syntax structure for the the term, the heart and soul of algebra?

Comment: "What *exactly* is a term? " --> What you're looking for here is a *grammar* for algebraic expressions. Once you have that, there isn't really any ambiguity as to what a "term" is, because the grammar defines what exactly makes up a term. You can either write one yourself, or find one somewhere. In any case, I might recommend holding off on the AST until you get the grammar hammered out.

Comment: Check out my example of algebra defined using grammars and rewrites: http://www.semdesigns.com/products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html  This approach defines the AST to *be* isomorphic to the grammar for algebraic expressions.

Comment: @user3580294 You're exactly right; I'm confusing grammar with AST. Ira Baxter: Thanks; I'll definitely take a look at it.

Comment: Did some looking around, and wasn't able to find a general grammar for algebraic expressions, unfortunately. Either I need to brush up on my Google-fu, or you're a bit out of luck and will have to write one yourself... I don't think writing your own would be too challenging, though, as long as you're careful. +1 for what I think is a good question, though.